# Magento 2 : Chekcout cart page qty with increase and decrease icon

Tags: checkout, cart

[image]

I want to customize the checkout cart as my own choice. I want to see checkout cart will show "+ -" to increase & decrease quantity by clicking + & - options. So I need someone's help who can help out from this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Override form.phtml file from module-checkout and keep inside your custom theme folder at below location,**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($){
        $('.more, .less').on("click",function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var currentQty = $this.siblings('.input-text').val();

            if($this.hasClass('more')){
                console.log(parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1));
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
                $this.siblings('.input-text').val(newAdd);
            }else{
               var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                $this.siblings('.input-text').val(newAdd); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Override default.phtml file from core module-checkout folder,

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

**add +- near to qty field,**

```
 <div class="control qty">
    <input id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
           name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
           data-cart-item-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getSku() ?>"
           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty() ?>"
           type="number"
           size="4"
           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>"
           class="input-text qty"
           maxlength="12"
           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
</div>
```

**Replace above core input qty field with below code,**

```
  <div class="control qty">
        <input id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
           name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
           data-cart-item-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getSku() ?>"
           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty() ?>"
           type="number"
           size="4"
           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>"
           class="input-text qty"
           maxlength="12"
           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
           <!-- more and less button -->
           <div class="more">+</div>
           <div class="less">-</div>
</div>
```

Clear cache and check in cart page.

Comment: thanks for your reply its working for me. but i want to update price with increasing quantity ....

Comment: @rakesh-jesadiya, many thanks for providing the simple solution.

Comment: @rakesh Thanks the above code is working for me, but there is one issue that the quantity is decrementing to 0 and less than that too. I want minimum qty to be 1.

Comment: This does change the qty number in the input however doesn't trigger the change action on qty, so it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a small solution magento 2.4.3 for the checkout/cart page:**

Here it is so that the buttons -/+ per click updates the data. But additionally with the entry in the input field an update button appears which updates the quantity by clicking on it.

copy:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

to your design folder:

```
app/design/{your_theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Change line 97:

```
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
```

to:

```
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" data-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>">
```

Change Line 99-115:

```
<div class="control qty">
    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               type="number"
               size="4"
               step="any"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
               data-item-qty="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="control qty" data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/update_qty": {}}'>
    <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
        <a class="qty -minus">-</a>
        <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
               name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               type="number"
               size="4"
               step="any"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
               class="input-text qty"
               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
               data-item-qty="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
        <a class="qty -plus">+</a>
    </label>
    <a class="hidden update-btn cursor-pointer" id="update-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Update')) ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

add a new file to your design folder: app/design/{your_theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'a.qty', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                productId = $(this).parents('td').data('id'),
                updateInput = $("#cart-" + productId + "-qty"),
                currentQty = updateInput.val();

            if ($this.hasClass('-plus')) {
                var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty) + parseInt(1);
                updateInput.val(newAdd);
                ajaxUpdate();
            } else if ($this.hasClass('-minus')) {
                if (currentQty > 1) {
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty) - parseInt(1);
                    updateInput.val(newAdd);
                }
                ajaxUpdate();
            }

        });
        $(document).on('change', 'input.input-text.qty', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                productId = $(this).parents('td').data('id'),
                updateButton = $("#update-" + productId + "-qty");

            updateButton.show().removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            $(updateButton).on('click', function () {
                ajaxUpdate();
            });
        });

        function ajaxUpdate() {
            var form = $('form#form-validate.form-cart');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res),
                        result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate.form-cart"),
                        sections = ['cart'];

                    form.replaceWith(result);

                    // The mini cart reloading
                    customerData.reload(sections, true);

                    // The totals summary block reloading
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    console.log(err.Message);
                }
            });
            return true;
        };
    });
});
```